# Within an ENT 2.0 account how do you write a SQL query to filter for Status = 'active' BY MID number?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Within an ENT 2.0 account how do you write a SQL query to filter for Status = 'active' BY MID number?

I want to understand how many "active" users we have by MID and I can only figure out how to query all subscribers, which doesn't filter it down by MID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible unless you build shared data extensions based on tracking extracts.  This is my biggest pet peeve with ET right now.   The child business unit status for a subscriber is also not retrievable via API.

Comment: Agree that the status within BU is not something exposed to the Query Activity. But in terms of API - one can certainly get the status of the subscriber within any BU. It is achievable if Client ID (which is in essence MID of the BU) is included into Retrieve request for the Subscriber object - Status field in this case will represent the status in the BU not Enterprise.

Comment: I stand corrected about the API status check.  Could have sworn it was not possible earlier this year.  I mocked up a sample landing page to confirm.